# XHTML Responsive Design with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, gridview, primefaces, xhtml

I used css grid to add responsiveness.

So how can i check the responsive from chrome browser ?
When i change the size of the chrome window(pic 01) it works fine but when i tried to use device toolbar(pic ) it doesn't shows correctly.

[ F12 --> (ctrl+shift+m) ]

[image: (pic 01)]

[image: (pic 0)]

**xhtml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
<title>Manage App</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<center><h1>Employee Application Form</h1></center>  
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-6 ui-sm-12">
    <center>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                <h:outputLabel for="empName" value="Name :" style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:inputText id="empName" value="#{employeeBean.empName}" />

                <h:outputLabel for="empId" value="Employee ID : " style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:inputText id="empId" value="#{employeeBean.empId}" />

                <h:outputLabel for="age" value="Age: " style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:inputText id="age" type="number" value="#{employeeBean.empAge}" />

                <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{employeeBean.saveEmployee}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-sm-12"></div>
</div> 
<div >
    <p:dataTable var="emp" value="#{employeeBean.empList}">

        <p:column headerText="Employee ID">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.empId}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Employee Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.empName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Employee Age">
            <h:outputText value="#{emp.empAge}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</div> 

<h3>Sample Layout</h3>
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" style="background: radial-gradient(circle,grey,blue);">Menu</div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            Bar
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed imperdiet, orci nec dictum convallis, ligula mauris vestibulum turpis, nec varius tortor quam at diam. Nullam a viverra nibh. In tincidunt tempor lectus quis vulputate. Pellentesque nec dui aliquam, lobortis est in, lobortis ante</div>
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Maecenas vel nisi aliquet, vulputate tortor id, laoreet massa. Maecenas mattis tristique bibendum. Suspendisse vel mi dictum, vestibulum lacus quis, pulvinar quam. Proin vulputate, nibh at finibus varius, leo eros lacinia elit, nec blandit odio tellus a justo. Donec nec ex auctor, tristique nulla nec, rutrum sapien.</div>
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Proin efficitur in leo eget ornare. Nam vestibulum neque sed velit sagittis sodales. Sed scelerisque hendrerit magna a hendrerit. Cras tempor sem at justo pharetra convallis. Curabitur vel sodales purus. Vestibulum interdum facilisis nulla imperdiet suscipit. Quisque lectus felis, condimentum eget hendrerit sit amet.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4 ui-sm-12"><p:graphicImage name="images/mock.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div>  
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4"><h:graphicImage library="images" name="mock.jpg"  style="width:100%" /></div> 
                <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-4"><p:graphicImage name="images/mock.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div>      
            </div>

            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">Phasellus faucibus purus volutpat mauris lacinia sodales. Ut sit amet sapien facilisis, commodo dui non, fringilla tellus. Quisque tempus facilisis nisi sodales finibus. Pellentesque neque orci, ullamcorper vitae ligula quis, dignissim euismod augue.</div>
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">Fusce ullamcorper congue massa, eget ullamcorper nunc lobortis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultrices dui eget dolor feugiat dapibus. Aliquam pretium leo et egestas luctus. Nunc facilisis gravida tellus.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone give some suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Isn't this pure chrome question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. i updated the topic and tags.

Comment: What kind programming language is this?

Comment: JSF with using primefaces but this is the xhtml file and primeface components are used here @FrankConijn

Comment: Which client side ends up as plain html and css and uses normal media queries etc for responsiveness